# Laravel Homestead not recognizing environment variables

Tags: php, laravel

So, this is my Homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: db_host
      value: localhost
    - key: db_database
      value: homestead
    - key: db_username
      value: homestead
    - key: db_password
      value: secret
```

However, I keep getting an error thrown saying that `Undefined index: db_host`, as can be seen here:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When adding the values to the yaml file did you provision your homestead with the following command `vagrant provision` or `vagrant up --provision`

Comment: @MattBurrow Yes, I did